# Javascript in Wicket 1.5

Tags: javascript, wicket, wicket-1.5

im looking for the Wicket 1.5 Way of doing the following tasks:

1. Add a external .js File to header of the Page from a Panel.
2. Add a `<script>...</script>` Tag at Bottom of Page from a Panel
3. Add some Javascript to the onLoad Event of the Body tag

There are lots of examples how to do this in Wicket 1.2 and 1.3 but these API are gone. 
Any good Wicket 1.5 Articles aboutJavascript/Ajax would be great.

Comment: You can post your own answer to the question and accept it.

Comment: And you can even get upvotes on that :-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HaBaLeS found it out himself:

```
add(new Behavior(){
        private final ResourceReference SOME_JS = new JavaScriptResourceReference(ChartTestPage.class, "some.js");

            @Override
            public void renderHead(Component component, IHeaderResponse response) {
                response.renderOnDomReadyJavaScript("alert('hello')"); //on Load
                response.renderJavaScriptReference(SOME_JS); //include js file
                response.renderJavaScript("alert('world');", "somescript"); //<script> tag
            }


        });
```

Comment: Hello, and what about if my "some.js" file is not in same folder but is an external resource, maybe in other location in my server, maybe external location... How I would create the `JavaScriptResourceReference`??

Thanks

Comment: You will have to extend ResourceReference and integrate java.net.HttpURLConnection in ResourceReference getResource(), and write the file to an OutputStream.